# How to parse BeautifulSoup List or Dict to Flask render Template and display output to html page?

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

i am new to flask and i am trying to display flask output to render template in html web page. i am getting output in console but its not displaying on html page.. how to display this result table to html page? or any best way to do this.. any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,redirect,url_for
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import cgi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods= ['POST','GET'])
def inputForm():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        STD = request.form['STDCode']
        return redirect(url_for('Search'))

    return render_template('Base.html')

@app.route('/Search', methods= ['POST','GET'])
def Search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        STD = request.form['STDCode']
        #STD=20
        url = ('http://1min.in/telecom/stdcode/{}'.format(STD))
        response = requests.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        Table = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-bordered')

        Table = Table[0]

        data = []
        for row in Table.find_all('tr'):
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            print(len(row))

            datainfo = {}

            datainfo['State'] = cells[0].find(text=True)
            datainfo['District'] = cells[1].find(text=True)
            datainfo['City'] = cells[2].find(text=True)
            datainfo['STDCode'] = cells[3].find(text=True)
            datainfo['ServiceArea'] = cells[4].find(text=True)
            datainfo['LCDA'] = cells[5].find(text=True)
            datainfo['SDCA'] = cells[6].find(text=True)

            data.append(datainfo)
            print(datainfo)

    return render_template('SearchResult.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Base.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h3>Input Form</h3>

  <div class="well text-center">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
        <form method="POST" class="form-inline">
            <input type="search" name="STDCode" placeholder="Enter STD 
  Code" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" 
  type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

SearchResult.html

```
{% include "Base.html" %}
<div>
    {% block body %}
    <table class="table table-striped" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>District</th>
                <th>City/Area</th>
                <th>STD Code</th>
                <th>service Area</th>
                <th>LDCA</th>
                <th>SDCA</th>
            </tr>

            {% for key, datainfo in data %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ datainfo['Name'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ datainfo['District'] }}</td>
                <td> {{ datainfo['City'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ datainfo['STDCode'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ datainfo['ServiceArea'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ datainfo['LCDA'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ datainfo['SDCA'] }} </td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor  %}
    </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add return statement inside `if` the condition:

```
return render_template('SearchResult.html', data=data)
```

**change app.py file**

```
@app.route('/Search', methods= ['POST','GET'])
def Search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        STD = request.form['STDCode']

        url = ('http://1min.in/telecom/stdcode/{}'.format(STD))
        response = requests.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        Table = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-bordered')

        if len(Table) <=0:
            return render_template('Base.html')

        Table = Table[0]

        datainfo = {}
        for row in Table.find_all('tr'):
            key = None
            value = None

            for cell in row.find_all("td"):
                _class = cell.get('class')
                if "td-name" in _class: 
                    key = cell.text.strip()
                elif "td-value" in _class:
                    value = cell.text.strip()

            if key is not None and value is not None:

                if "STD Code" in key:
                    span = row.find("span",{'class':"highlight"})
                    datainfo[key] = span.text.strip()
                else:
                    datainfo[key] = value

        return render_template('SearchResult.html',data=datainfo)

    return render_template('Base.html')
```

**Change SearchResult.html file**

```
{% include "Base.html" %}
<div>
    {% block body %}
    <table class="table table-striped" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>District</th>
                <th>City/Area</th>
                <th>STD Code</th>
                <th>service Area</th>
                <th>LDCA</th>
                <th>SDCA</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> {{ data['State'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ data['District'] }}</td>
                <td> {{ data['City/Area'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ data['STD Code'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ data['Service Area'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ data['LDCA'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ data['SDCA'] }} </td>

            </tr>

    </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: changes made according above but showing --Type error :The view function did not return a valid response.The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: @user10146017  You should also add `return render_template('Base.html')` outside of `if` condition for Get request.

Comment: @bahratk  how to get key, value for some td having no class name in tr and also in case of dynamic numbers of rows i.e changing row numbers

Answer (score 0):

you need to [pass your data as argument](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates) to `render_template()` like this:

`return render_template('SearchResult.html', data=data)`

EDIT:

```
@app.route('/Search', methods= ['POST','GET'])
def Search():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # your code here, excluding the data = [] line
    return render_template('SearchResult.html', data=data)
```

or

```
@app.route('/Search', methods= ['POST','GET'])
def Search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # your code here
        return render_template('SearchResult.html', data=data)
    return render_template('Base.html')
```

Comment: Its showing error -- UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment

Comment: you need to properly handle the GET request (at the moment data is defined only when POST request). one way is to define `data=[]` outside/before the if block. Another option (worse in my opinion) is to have second return within the if block, where you pass data and keep the other one as it is now

Comment: made changes now its showing--IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: please, edit your question and post the full traceback - I guess it's problem with your parsing the Table object - that's the only  place where you use indexing (i.e. it's a different problem)